# Cannot access a disposed object

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

Hi could you help me with this error?
`Cannot access a disposed object.
Object name: 'DataContext accessed after Dispose.'.`

in my GUI

```
 private void InitializePage()
    {
        cbCategory.DataSource = stock.StockCategory.Get();

    }
```

in Datamodel

```
 public IEnumerable<StockCategory> Get()
    {
        using (leDataContext db = new leDataContext())
        {
            try
            {
                var r = from s in db.StockCategories
                        select s;
                return r;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Logger.Error(typeof(StockCategory), ex.ToString());
                throw;
            }

        }

    }
```

Comment: it works if i (from s in db.StockCategories select s).Tolist(). But putting a Tolist() there but return as ienumerable() is it correct?

Comment: Can one access a disposed object once it's disposed?

Comment: This post is terrible. Pieces of code are missing, you didn't describe what you want to accomplish, so how are we suppose to help you? Please, correct those issues and then we will be able to give you some advice.

Comment: This code is a little strange... you haven't wrapped up the top method 'Get()' properly for a start...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You're disposing the `DataContext` but returning something that still depends on it.

Options:

- Don't dispose the `DataContext`. I know this sounds weird, but guidance from the LINQ to SQL team (well, Matt Warren) has indicated that in *most* cases (i.e. if you're not doing anything out of the ordinary) disposal is not required
- Call `ToList()` *inside* the `Get()` method's `using` block.

Note that using a query expression with just a degenerate query is reasonably pointless. (If this is within your own code, even the implicit `Select(s => s)` won't actually be useful.)

I would suggest changing your method to:

```
public IList<StockCategory> GetAllStockCategories()
{
    using (leDataContext db = new leDataContext())
    {
        return db.StockCategories.ToList();
    }
}
```

Comment: I call to list() but it doesn't work. Though the list is not null when it is returned when I try to serialize it I still get the error. I want to understand why.

Comment: @D3v: I suggest you ask a new question with all the relevant details. (In particular, do any of the list entries contain other entities which might be lazily serialized? Have you experimented with not disposing the DataContext?)

Answer (score 4):

Because of lazy-loading there, the query isn't really executed on the linq statement line. It is executed when you loop over it, or in this case - when you run ToList on it.

When it is executed it must be inside the data context... which is not the case here. You can either return a List from the Get method or insert the setting of the cbCategory.DataSource value into the `using (leDataContext...)` scope.