# Cannot access data object after dispose even though its a list

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I am getting this error:

> Cannot access a disposed object.
>       Object name: 'DataContext accessed after Dispose.'.

For this code:

```
...
ViewData["AdSlots"] = dbc.AdSlots.Where(a => a.PublisherId == publisherId).ToList();
dbc.Dispose();
```

When I use this code for the view:

```
grid.Column(header: "Ad Size", style: "ad-size", format: @<text>@item.AdSize.Width x @item.AdSize.Height</text>),
```

This is in MVC3 btw.

Does anyone know why this is happening? Shouldn't it have been stored in memory and worked or do I need to explicitly state something that I want associations kept as well?

Thanks

Comment: You disposed of it, why do you think you should be able to access it???  In a language without garbage collection you can usually get away with this but it's still very bad programming that will occasionally blow up on you.  In a garbage collected language it's much more likely to go boom.

Comment: I have converted it to a list though... shouldn't it stay in memory?

Comment: You used dispose.  The component is gone.

Comment: Of course it should.  Are you sure the error isn't elsewhere?  Are you passing a **non-deferred** query to your view elsewhere?

Comment: @LorenPechtel - he disposed of it **after** he materialized the query.  That should be fine.

Comment: Is this LINQ-To-SQL? Have a look: http://geekswithblogs.net/TimH/archive/2008/06/03/system.objectdisposedexception-cannot-access-a-disposed-object.--getting-linq-to.aspx or http://stackoverflow.com/a/5350163/284240

Comment: What you got from the <strong>dbc</strong> were the AdSolts and in your view you are trying to access the AdSize which was not loaded from the database thanks to the lazy loading nature of Linq-to-SQL

Comment: @epignosisx - bingo - lazy loading.  Put that as an answer and I'll +1 it

Comment: @AdamRackis posted the explanation with a code snippet.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that you are querying the database for **AdSolts** and disposing of it right after. Then in your view your code tries to access the **AdSize** which tries to access the database again but thanks to the lazy loading nature of Linq-to-SQL AdSize was not loaded the first time and since the data context is disposed, it throws that exception.

You can solve your problem by using **DataLoadOptions**.

```
List<AdSlot> list;
using(var dbc = new DbDataContext())
{
    var loadOptions = new DataLoadOptions();
    loadOptions.LoadWith<AdSlot>(n => n.AdSize);
    dbc.LoadOptions = loadOptions;

    list = dbc.AdSlots.Where(a => a.PublisherId == publisherId).ToList();
}

ViewData["AdSlots"] = list;
```

Answer (score 1):

so now i wonder what would happen if you leave the same code as posted by epignosisx but remove the loadoptions? since you are putting the list into a new variable?